# What is the difference between data transfer and weight transfer when rigging?

Tags: animation, mesh, rigging, weight-painting, vertex-groups

I understand that data transfer copies the vertices from the mesh to the cloth, but wouldn't weight transfer do the same thing since weight is calculated by vertices (not faces or edges)? Do they mean the same thing?

Comment: Basically the same thing, but one is modifier, other one in operator